# Setting a computer room number with a PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Thank you all for your replies. I have corrected the errors in my code, although they were just a cut and paste error. Here is an example with the error I get. If I do for example:

```
PS > Set-ADComputer "VM-WINDOWS7" -Location "NA/HQ/Building A"
PS > Get-ADComputer "VM-WINDOWS7" -Properties location |select-object location
```

It works and I get the result:

```
Location
--------
NA/HQ/Building A
```

But when I do:

```
PS > Set-ADComputer "VM-WINDOWS7" -RoomNumber "7"
```

Or

```
PS > Set-ADComputer "VM-WINDOWS7" -RoomNumber @{Replace="7"}
```

I get the error:

```
Set-ADComputer: Cannot find a parameter that matches the name "RoomNumber".
At line: 1 Character: 41
+ Set-ADComputer "VM-WINDOWS7" -RoomNumber <<<<  @{Replace="7"}
    + CategoryInfo: InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-ADComputer], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADComputer
```

It’s like I said before, the parameter RoomNumber is not recognized, so I thought maybe it has another name, like for example ( Account name in AD = SAMAccountName in PowerShell ).

Comment: Need to fix a double quote situation on `Write-Host "Room number set to...` line. Looks like the first quote is not the correct character, just delete it and retype it and you also don't want to put quotes around your variables inside of that. You also have an extra "o" in your problem line `Rooom`

Comment: Your code _appears_ right but I see a typo here: `@ {RooomNumber="$RoomNumber"}` should be `@{RooomNumber="$RoomNumber"}`. I will keep looking. Also are you getting errors? You need to describe with detail what is happening. You will get a solution faster.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of issues here for sure. You have mistyped the AD attribute `roomNumber` as `rooomNumber`. You also have a space where your hashtable is declared.

Much like [ssaviers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/747675/ssaviers), I see some smart quotes as well. Those can usually come from a copy and paste but you need to be careful if those are in your code.

```
“ - smartquote
" - regular double quote
```

That being said the *problematic part* might just need to be updated:

```
Set-ADComputer "$HostName" -Replace @{roomNumber = "$RoomNumber"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:

Set-ADComputer doesn't have a -roomnumber parameter. But it can be modified using Add, Replace, Clear or Remove parameters.
The 'ROOMNUMBER' field is LDAP so it has a different syntax:

Set-ADComputer $HostName -replace @{roomNumber='$RoomNumber'} (that's what i used in the first place but i didn’t write it correctly)

Looks like a lot of the fields in AD especially for computers need to be done this way.

Anyway thank you all for your ideas and supports.

Cheers.